# How to set properties of Associated class in spring mvc

Tags: spring-mvc

i have two entity class : User and Address
User class : it has many other properties plus associated class address

```
Entity
@Table(name = "T_USER_DETAILS")
public class User {


//@GenericGenerator(name = "generator",strategy = "sequence-identity",parameters = { @Parameter(name = "sequence",value = "USER_ID_SEQ")} )

@GenericGenerator(name = "generator",strategy = "increment")    
@Id 
@GeneratedValue(generator = "generator")
@Column(name = "USER_ID")
private int userid;

@Column(name = "USER_FIRSTNAME")
private String firstname;
@Column(name = "USER_AGE")
private int age;


//creating many to one relationship between address class and student class
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "ADDRESS_ID")
private Address address;
```

here is the address class which also an enity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_ADDRESS_DETAILS")
public class Address {



    @GenericGenerator(name = "idgenerator", strategy = "increment")
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "idgenerator")
    @Column(name = "ADDRESS_ID")
    private int addressId;

    @Column(name = "ADDRESS_LINE1")
    private String address_line1;

    @Column(name = "ADDRESS_LINE2")
    private String address_line2;
```

in my form i am creating a command bean for user class and binding it in my controller class as:

```
<form:form method = "post" action = "register.html" commandName = "newUser">

<br>
<h2><i>Create new account</i></h2>
<br>
Enter the firstname<br>
<input type = "text" size = "30" name = "firstname">
<font color = "red"> <form:errors path = "firstname" cssClass = "error"/></font><br>
Enter the lastname<br>
<input type = "text" size = "30" name = "lastname">
<font color = "red"> <form:errors path = "lastname" cssClass = "error"/></font><br>
Enter the password<br>
<input type = "password" size = "30" name = "password">
<font color = "red"> <form:errors path = "password" cssClass = "error"/></font><br>
Enter the Email Id<br>
<input type = "text" size = "30" name = "emailId">
<font color = "red"><form:errors path = "emailId" cssClass = "error"/><br></font>
Enter the phone number<br>
<input type = "text" size = "30" name = "phonenumber">
<font color = "red"><form:errors path = "phonenumber" cssClass = "error"/></font><br>
Enter the age<br>
<input type  = "text" size = "30" name = "age"/>
<font color = "red"><form:errors path = "age" cssClass = "error"/></font><br><br>

Enter the Address<br>
<input type = "textbox" name = "address" size = "30">
<font color = "red"><form:errors path = "address" cssClass = "error"/></font><br>

<div align = "center">



<input type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "submit">
```

controller:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String register(@ModelAttribute("newUser") User user,BindingResult result,Model model,HttpSession session,HttpServletRequest request) //retrieve the backing bean with in the user attribute 
{
..
}
```

my problem here is how can i assign the properties of the address class which i want to send from form like city,state,country...
what changes i need to do in my jsp page and my controller class.
Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use the `<form:input` tag with associations of the properties of a joined class like the following:

```
<form:form commandName="person" method="post" action="${formAction}">
    <div class="form">
        <p>User</p>
            <form:input path="firstname" />
            <form:input path="address.address_line1" />

            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </div>
</form:form>
```

Remember, the key is to use the form input path to match the properties of the joined class. You can then use this method for all of the other associations used in the form bean.

Answer (score 0):

You should change the address bean to add properties for City, State etc (amongst other things provides for a good validation also using annotations). Thereafter, you will have to split the input to one per property of the address bean; You can then use `sping:bind` tag with the notation `address.city`

```
<form:form commandName="person" method="POST" action = "register.html">

   <spring:bind path="address.city">
    <input type = "textbox" name = "address.city" size = "30">
   </spring:bind>

   ...
   ...
</form:form>
```